# Unique constraints on TEXT columns in JPA using MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, innodb, unique

We need to store a long UTF-8 string into a MySQL database which has to be checked for uniqueness. This is the current configuration:

```
@Column(unique = true,length = 8000,columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String text;
```

but since MySQL needs an index prefix to be specified for both `BLOB` and `TEXT` fields, this fails with the following error:

```
BLOB/TEXT column 'path' used in key specification without a key length
```

How can I properly configure my ORM mapping to support such use case?

Comment: MySQL cannot index TEXT fields longer than a certain length IIRC and only allows up to 1000 (left-most) to be part of the index, and don't know of any ORM that allows specification of that separation from the length of the whole column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [calculating a hash value for your text string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_value)?  Then you could store the hash value and just check for uniqueness on the hash value.  Any collisions you get with the hash value you then check the actual text strings.  If they are different then you include a sequence value. if not you've found your error.  So your table is

Hash, Sequence (unique within the same Hash value), TextString

and your unique index is

Hash, Sequence

To test for uniqueness calculate the Hash value and attempt to store it with a zero sequence.  If you can't store it at sequence zero then compare the text string at sequence zero.  If they are the same you found a duplicate text.  If they are different attempt to store at sequence 1.  Repeat until you find a duplicate text string at that sequence number or you don't fail on storing it in the database with the next available sequence number.

The trick is figuring out a hash algorithm that doesn't give you very many duplicates and can handle a long text string. Even better would be a great ORM that could do this for you.

Comment: Eventually, we went this path while trying to find any more direct answer to my question. As we understood there's no ORM fairy powder that's going to help us with, it also became the final solution to our problem. Thanks for putting it into writing.